# Query sum with 3 joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I need to sum the 3rd column and show in a query
grouped by date and id

this is the exi Table

```
+------+------------+----------+
|exiID |  exiDate   | exiavail |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/22/2017 |   255.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/23/2017 |    45.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/23/2017 |   102.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/23/2017 |    55.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

this is the rec Table

```
+------+------------+----------+
|recID |  recDate   | recreciv |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/22/2017 |    15.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/23/2017 |    12.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/23/2017 |    32.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/24/2017 |     9.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

this is the sal Table

```
+------+------------+----------+
|salID |   salDate  | salreciv |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/22/2017 |    21.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/23/2017 |     7.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 012  | 01/23/2017 |    11.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
| 011  | 01/24/2017 |     2.00 |
+------+------------+----------+
```

Query Needed Join tables and SUM exiavail, recreciv, salreciv 
grouping by Date and ID :(
the query result need to be like this

```
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
|     Date   |  ID  | exiavail | recreciv | salreciv |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/22/2017 | 011  |   255.00 |     0.00 |    21.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/22/2017 | 012  |     0.00 |    15.00 |     0.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/23/2017 | 011  |    45.00 |    12.00 |     0.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/23/2017 | 012  |   157.00 |    32.00 |    18.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/24/2017 | 011  |     0.00 |     9.00 |     2.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| 01/24/2017 | 012  |     0.00 |     0.00 |     0.00 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: You show 01/24/2017 for id 12 in your results table, but this record does not exist in any of the three tables.  How would the query know to display this record?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN   on date and id 
(Assuming that the ID match in the 3 tables )

```
select 
  a.exiDate as date
  , a.exiID as id 
  , sum(a.exiavail) exiavail
  , sum(b.recreciv) recreciv
  , sum(c.salreciv) salreciv
from exi as a
left join rec as b on a.date = b.date and a.exiID = b.recID
left join sal as c on a.date = c.date and a.exiID = c.salID
group by a.exiDate,  a.exiID
```

Answer (score 0):

The example data shows that the ID and date pairs are not the same in all 3 tables. Need a dataset of all possible pairs then join each table to that dataset with compound join on the two fields and do the sums and grouping in that query.

A UNION query can construct the all pairs dataset.

```
SELECT exiID AS ID, exiDate AS TxnDate AS Source FROM exi
UNION SELECT recID, recDate FROM rec
UNION SELECT salID, salDate FROM sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is helps. You will need to update the table names but I hope this sets you up on the right track. Basically, you will need to sum up each value from each table and GROUP by ID and Date

```
    if object_id ('TESTING1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TESTING1
    if object_id ('TESTING2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TESTING2
    Create table TESTING1
    (id INT,
     Date DATETIME,
      val  INT)

       INSERT INTO dbo.testing1 values ('11', '01/23/2017', '255')
       INSERT INTO dbo.testing1 values ('11', '01/23/2017', '45')
       INSERT INTO dbo.testing1 values ('12', '01/22/2017', '102')
       INSERT INTO dbo.testing1 values ('12', '01/23/2017', '55')

       Create table TESTING2
       (id INT,
         Date DATETIME,
       val1 INT)


  INSERT INTO dbo.testing2 values ('12', '01/22/2017', '15')
  INSERT INTO dbo.testing2 values ('11', '01/23/2017', '12')
  INSERT INTO dbo.testing2 values ('12', '01/24/2017', '32')
  INSERT INTO dbo.testing2 values ('11', '01/23/2017', '9')



  SELECT distinct a.id, a.date, c.table1val,  b.table2val
  from testing1 a
  join (select id, date, sum(val1) as table2val
    from dbo.testing2
    group by id, date) b on b.id = a.id and b.date = a.date

   join (select id, date, sum(val) as table1val
    from dbo.testing1
     group by id, date) c on c.id = a.id and c.date = a.date
```